# How to associate User data with custom module?

Tags: users

I'm thinking about a custom module where I need to save additional data (like user logs from other software, customer data, etc.) that'd go into a custom module user table.
How would I associate that with the user? Just the user ID?
Or is there anything else that I might want to save for uses that I might not yet know (Views, Domain Acess, Panels, Context, ...) or can I get all required data just be joining the UserID everywhere?

Comment: Have you checked [Feeds module] (https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) already? It allows you to bring in external data and relate it to existing Drupal entities using an easy administration.

Comment: That is true - I played around with it. But I'm not certain whether it's enough. It can create Nodes but my data seems to be a bit more complex and it might be more reasonable to have it in an optimised table.  
But having nodes would be nice of course.

Comment: I hear you. IMO using Feeds gives you the benefit of a robust and mature module that already does all the heavy lifting for you. I've done projects where the external data wasn't Fed in and it became a non-scalable headache after a while. Feeds has a lot of API flexibilty... check out this [tutorial] (https://www.drupal.org/node/622700) for many great tips and guides on how to implement your own customization.

Comment: In my opinion, Feeds would only be useful if the software from which you are drawing the information can export in a format Feeds natively uses. Otherwise, I think a custom module is better because you are then not constrained by any changes to the Feeds module or its API - any changes would require a rewrite of parts of your site, whereas a custom module only changes when you change it

Comment: The problem is the kind or amount of data I guess.
Should be similar like data mining/logs/analytics table. I estimate on average for 500 users, 200 nodes, every day - 100.000 a day, so 3.6 Mio per year. I'd like to use d3 etc. for visualisation (not Views). Where as .. I just read more about it and saw it would be possible to put the feeds into MongoDB and that could go a long way. Maybe that's the way to go.

Comment: @Chris, it seems like you answered your own question, you should answer it and accept it so it's off the unanswered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual there are plenty of ways to do something with Drupal.
Of course it would be possible to create a content type and import it via Feeds but sometimes (in case it might become plenty of data) it could be better to use a different approach.

So far it seems I'd go with MongoDB, the appropriate module and get the data into the DB using JSON and try to relate that to the current user if or where needed. Due to the amount of data and the visualisation it seems to be better to go the Document DB way.